# How to allow passthrough of object fields that are not specified in the schema?

Tags: javascript, express, zod

I am trying to validate just a subset of my request data using `zod`. However, it is filtering out everything that I do not explicitly specify.

```
const { z } = require('zod');

const schema = z.object({
  params: z.object({ dependent_id: z.string() }),
})

const req = {
  params: { dependent_id: "blah", bar: "baz" },
  body: { foo: "bar" },
  query: {}
}

const test = async () => {
 const { params, body, query } = await schema.parseAsync(req);
  console.log("params: ", params)
  console.log("body: ", body)
  console.log("query: ", query)
}

test()
```

This is printing out:

```
params:  { dependent_id: 'blah' }         // expect it to print { dependent_id: "blah", "bar": baz }
body:  undefined                          // expect it to print { foo: "bar" }
query:  undefined                         // expect it to print {},
```

Is there a way to tell it to ignore everything that is not part of the schema?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Comment: one wonders what you're using zod for if you're not going to type the majority of the response. Seems like you may as well just `const { params, body, query } = req`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to keep unrecognised keys you can use [`.passthrough`](https://zod.dev/?id=passthrough). This will make zod pass through unknown keys.

```js
const test = async () => {
  const { params, body, query } = await schema.passthrough().parseAsync(req);
  console.log("params: ", params)
  console.log("body: ", body)
  console.log("query: ", query)
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for nested objects.  best I can tell you have to declare `passthrough()` on every nested object.